# assertion failed: No predefined schema found, and no Parquet data files

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

unfortunately I have another problems with Scala and SparkSql.
The problem is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No predefined schema found, and no Parquet data files or summary files found under file:/user/hive/warehouse/products/bc223562-ee45-42a6-b9a0-05635efb3e59.parquet.
```

I'm using the Cloudera VM (Virtual Box environment): the machine provide a single cluster manager with one node and Cloudera environment installed, with some services like Spark, Hive, Impala, ...

Now I'm trying to test Scala with SparkSql, and I have an error that I can't resolved. This is my code:

```
package org.test.spark

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object TestSelectAlgorithm {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("TestSelectAlgorithm")
      .setMaster("local")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    import sqlContext._

    val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/products/bc223562-ee45-42a6-b9a0-05635efb3e59.parquet")
    parquetFile.registerTempTable("products")

    val result = sqlContext.sql("select * from default.products")
    parquetFile.show()
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/07/01 01:31:34 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/07/01 01:31:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/01 01:31:35 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloudera
16/07/01 01:31:35 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloudera
16/07/01 01:31:35 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(cloudera); users with modify permissions: Set(cloudera)
16/07/01 01:31:36 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 57073.
16/07/01 01:31:37 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/07/01 01:31:37 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.0.2.15:36679]
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 36679.
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-1ad66510-ad8f-4239-b4bf-1410135c84f5
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 1619.3 MB
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/07/01 01:31:38 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
16/07/01 01:31:39 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/07/01 01:31:39 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 45098.
16/07/01 01:31:39 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 45098
16/07/01 01:31:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/07/01 01:31:39 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:45098 with 1619.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 45098)
16/07/01 01:31:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO ParquetRelation: Listing file:/user/hive/warehouse/products/bc223562-ee45-42a6-b9a0-05635efb3e59.parquet on driver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No predefined schema found, and no Parquet data files or summary files found under file:/user/hive/warehouse/products/bc223562-ee45-42a6-b9a0-05635efb3e59.parquet.
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetRelation$MetadataCache$$readSchema(ParquetRelation.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache$$anonfun$12.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache$$anonfun$12.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:421)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache.refresh(ParquetRelation.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetRelation$$metadataCache$lzycompute(ParquetRelation.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetRelation$$metadataCache(ParquetRelation.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$6.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$6.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:202)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation.dataSchema(ParquetRelation.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema$lzycompute(interfaces.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema(interfaces.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.baseRelationToDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:316)
    at org.test.spark.TestSelectAlgorithm$.main(TestSelectAlgorithm.scala:20)
    at org.test.spark.TestSelectAlgorithm.main(TestSelectAlgorithm.scala)
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/07/01 01:31:40 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-2e652280-6b19-4bc5-b686-49e1fba5f7e8
```

First, I'm sure that the path is correct about the parquet file:

```
/user/hive/warehouse/products/bc223562-ee45-42a6-b9a0-05635efb3e59.parquet
```

But the error tell to me: `No predefined schema found`

Anyone can help me, please?
On the web, and more precisely on stackoverflow.com I have founded some articles.. but they cannot help me!

Comment: It is parquet error to verify just use hive or some parquetread apart from spark to validate your parquet file.

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand: the file in HDFS in in parquet format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the path:

"hdfs:////user/hive/warehouse/products/bc223562-ee45-42a6-b9a0-05635efb3e59.parquet"

or try to tell Spark about your Hadoop environment (I don't know how to write it in Scala but try to convert this Java Code):

```
File coreSite = new File("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml");
File hdfsSite = new File("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml");
Configuration hConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration();
hConf.addResource(new Path(coreSite.getAbsolutePath()));
hConf.addResource(new Path(hdfsSite.getAbsolutePath()));

SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
```

Comment: Now I have tried:  `val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8888/user/hive/warehouse/products/bc223562-ee45-42a6-b9a0-05635efb3e59.parquet")` but this did not works! Now I'm searching the hadoopConfiguration in Scala..

Comment: Where do you execute the scala script? directly on Quickstart VM? or remote? and can you tell me the spark-submit command that you used?

Comment: Directly on the Virtual Machine, on Eclipse environment and Maven Project with a POM.xml configuration.

Comment: Ok, It's very strange. The file could be corrupted, try to check it as follow [link](http://big-analytics.blogspot.it/2015/10/inspecting-apache-parquet-file.html)

Comment: Did you get this resolved ? . Im also facing same issue and though I followed above steps it didn't worked. If its resolved for you can you please explain the changes you have made.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurred if specified path doesn't have parquet specific data or could be empty. Please validate your files before creating dataframe

Comment: Seems like pretty horrible exception handling if it fails with an assertion error on an empty file.

Comment: yup agreed ...could be treated as bug